# Second bit of javascript that changes a setting in a previous block of javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to modify some javascript on a Squarespace site but I don't have access to it – I can only add additional code after the original block of script. The original code is as follows:

```
<script>
    Static.SQUARESPACE_CONTEXT = {
        "appDomain": "squarespace.com",

...

        "tweakJSON": {
            "gallery-auto-play": "false",
            "gallery-style": "Center",
            "gallery-transition": "Slide",
            "galleryPlaySpeed": "3.0",
            "index-aspect-ratio": "Auto",
            "navigation-position": "Bottom",
            "product-gallery-auto-crop": "true",
            "product-image-auto-crop": "true"
        },

...

        }
    };
    SquarespaceFonts.loadViaContext();
    Squarespace.load();
</script>
```

I've removed a bunch of additional code to shorten things up but if you need the full code I can post it. I'm trying to change the `"gallery-style": "Center"` to `"gallery-style": "Full Bleed"`

If you need further info just let me know. Any help would be much appreciate. Also, I'm not a programmer so if you could keep it dumbed down for me that would be great.

-- Additional info:

Thought this might help. Here's the site I'm referring to: architechstairs.squarespace.com What I'm looking to do is have the home page "Full Bleed" while all other gallery pages on the site will be "Center". Unfortunately Squarespace only allows me to set one overall gallery style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Static.SQUARESPACE_CONTEXT.tweakJSON["gallery-style"] = 'Full Bleed';`